# Bitcoin JSON PHP RPC Client not connecting

Tags: php, json, rpc, bitcoin

I am following the development tutorial here. https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_(JSON-RPC)#PHP and using the phprpc http://jsonrpcphp.org.

I have properly configured my bitcoin configuration file with the correct username / password. Bitcoin is running in daemon mode. All prereqs have been met.

When attempting to send commands through bitcoind, i get no response, errors, or alerts. It is becoming quite frustrating as every detail checks out. I get a blank page. (Not error type as nothing follows on the page).

Any help is really appreciated.

Server is Ubuntu with Bitcoind
My PHP version is  5.5.3

Comment: have you enabled `display_errors` and set a proper debug value for `error_reporting` ?

Comment: display errors is set in the ini file. Its my dev vps

Comment: Is it a shell script you are testing? are you on Linux? then I would try to call with `strace` in order to see whats happening behind the scenes

Comment: its a php script that interacts with a shell script via rpc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching I found that with PHP 5.5.x JSON support for PHP was not included in Ubuntu's build due to a licensing conflict.

Use the command `sudo apt-get install php5-json` to install support and restart apache. This solution worked seamless.

No idea why PHP wasn't logging an error.